# Grafana Dashboard shows 'Active users' as 1 when executed Jmeter script for 100 threads

Tags: jmeter, grafana

We could integrate `Jmeter + InfluxDB + Grafana` to monitor real time results. `Jmeter` Test plan has Threads as '100' with Ramp up 100 seconds. After the execution was expecting 'Active Users' will reflect '100' users in `Grafana Dashboard` however it shows 1 user.

Jmeter TestPlan: 5.2 version
Thread Group: Number of Threads/Users - 100
Ramp Up: 100 seconds
Loop Count: 1

On `Grafana` Dashboard: configured with Jmeter Dashboard (3.2 and up) board from `Grafana`.
Active users 1, Throughput req/sec - shows 100.

Should Active users show 100 or 1? Tried different Dashboards available, in every case the same results.
Please guide.

[image]

Comment: How your test results makes it from JMeter (through Influx, as far as I get) to Grafana - could you elaborate pls?

Comment: Yes, Jmeter results are stored in InfluxDB. Fetching these results (DataSource) to Grafana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more loops in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), given your [Sampler(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) response time is 1 second or less you will run into the situation when 1st thread has already finished executing the Samplers and was shut down and the next one hasn't been yet started.

Another option is to reduce ramp-up, in this case you should see more concurrency.

More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/)